# Call base virtual method by pointer to function from derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, function-pointers

I need to call the base method A::foo() from derived class by pointer.

```
#include <iostream>
struct A{
    virtual void foo() { std::cout << "A::foo()" << std::endl; }
};

struct B:A{
    virtual void foo() { std::cout << "B::foo()" << std::endl; }
    void callBase(void (A::*f)()){
        (this->*f)();
    }
};

int main(){
    B* p=new B();
    p->callBase(&A::foo);
}
```

This code output "B::foo". Is it possible to call A::foo() by pointer to method?

Comment: I don't think you can. However, I have been wrong in the past :) Let's hope someone more knowledgeable than me knows a way.

Comment: You can call it directly like `p->A::foo();` but not through a pointer to member function (which I guess is the point of virtual functions).

Comment: I believe you work around this by having a non-virtual `bar` that does the work, and have `foo` delegate to `bar`, `callBase` then calls `bar`. This is more logical since polymorphism means `B` should always call its own `foo`

Comment: @PasserBy I just don't understand: I can explicitly specify class in hierarchy which method should be called like A::foo(). Here I do similar thing &A::foo. Virtual methods probably have different pointers. I guess this stupid assymetric behaviour related with vtable implementation.

Comment: @EgorDudyak This isn't "stupid assymetric behaviour", it is doing exactly what was intended, aka polymorphism. Consider `A* a = new B; auto p = &A::foo; (a->*p)();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can do something similar using some tricks with overwriting the value of `this`. You probably should never try to do that though, `vtable` pointers aren't meant to be modified by hand.

To do what you described, we need to have the pointer to A's `vtable`. Our object `p` has only pointer to B's `vtable`, so we need to store second pointer in a field within A's constructor.

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
struct A{
    virtual void foo() { std::cout << "A::foo()" << std::endl; }
    int *a_vtable_ptr;
    // First, save value of A's vtable pointer in a separate variable.
    A() { a_vtable_ptr = *(int**)this; }
};

struct B:A{
    virtual void foo() { std::cout << "B::foo()" << std::endl; }
    void callBase(void (A::*f)()){
        int *my_vtable_ptr = *(int**)this;
        // Then modify vtable pointer of given object to one that corresponds to class A.
        *(int**)this = a_vtable_ptr;
        (this->*f)(); // Call the method as usual.
        // Restore the original vtable pointer.
        *(int**)this = my_vtable_ptr;
    }
};

// Function main() is not modified.
int main(){
    B* p=new B();
    void (A::*f)() = &A::foo;
    p->callBase(f);
}
```

Output:

```
A::foo()

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Virtual methods are designed to implement polymorphism and pointers to virtual methods supports their polymorphic behavior. But you given the possibility to call the base method by explicitly calling `p->A::foo()`.

So if you want to call base method by pointer, you should make it non-virtual (as @PasserBy mentioned in comments).

Code example:

```
struct A {
    virtual void foo() { std::cout << "A::foo()" << std::endl; }
    void bar() { std::cout << "A::bar()" << std::endl; }
    void callBase(void (A::*f)()) { (this->*f)(); }
};

struct B : A {
    virtual void foo() { std::cout << "B::foo()" << std::endl; }
    void bar() { std::cout << "B::bar()" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    A* p = new B();
    p->foo();
    p->bar();
    p->callBase(&A::foo);
    p->callBase(&A::bar);
    p->A::foo();
    p->A::bar();
}
```

Output:

```
B::foo()
A::bar()
B::foo()
A::bar()
A::foo()
A::bar()
```